# Can Xcode 6.1 be the reason for bugs in code

Tags: xcode, ios8, xcode6.1, uideviceorientation, xcode-6.2

I use a non-depracated device orientation code that works perfectly for all iOS 7 simulator and devices. And for iOS 8 it works on iPad 2, iPhone 4s, iPhone 5s, iPhone 5. However, on iOS 8 it won't work on iPad Air, iPad Retina, iPhone 6+, iPhone 6.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Can Xcode 6.1 be the reason why certain code doesn't work and then that code would work on Xcode 6.2?  (i've been told code works on Xcode 6.2)

Comment: It's too wide your question but sometimes happens. I'm working about 3 years with Xcode and every upgrade you have several surprises. Remember, you use Xcode for recompile your code so, if you have a new version of it, you use a new SDK and you generate a different code (even for the same code) ... you must take your sit, test all your app and enjoy it :) ... Now, specifically about orientation issues, with iOS 8 is completely different... but you can start check with your .plist about orientations.

Comment: Which Xcode version do you use? Does the code above work on your Xcode version for iPhone 6/6+?

Comment: I know iOS 8 uses screen bounds for orientation but that's specifically for landscape orientation to get the different sizes. I don't need to change any sizes. I'm just doing Portrait and Upside Down. my info.plist is Item 0= Portrait(bottom home button) and item 1=Portrait (top home button)

Comment: Is it possible for you to check if the above code works for portrait/upside down orientation on Xcode 6.2 for iPhone 6/6+? There's nothing else needed but to add that code.

Comment: Do you use Auto Layout? If your answer is no (like me), let me tell you about my experience. I have a lot of problems with the last upgrade (like you). I have 6 apps in App Store and definitely the last upgrade was the last with no Auto Layout (Xcode 6.1). I starting introduce AutoLayout in my apps. Why? Because the flow of how control the screen orientation is completely different and I had to many problems. Sometimes have strange behavior and I had write workarounds to fix them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73093/discussion-between-beto-bens-and-jet).